# React not rendering redirecting page content

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

React router v4 is redirecting to about page but not rendering the about page contents infact its on the same home page with home page contents but then the url changes

Ex:

localhost:3000  // App page from here if about click

localhost:3000/About   // about page content is of App page

Following code for index app and about js

index.js

```js
import { BrowserRouter,Route,Switch,Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import App from './App';
ReactDOM.render(
    ( 
        <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/" component={App}/>           
            <Redirect for="*" to="/" />
        </Switch>       
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
, document.getElementById('root')
);
```

app.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import About from './About';
import {Route,Link} from 'react-router-dom'

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state=({name:"",
                    age:"",
                    button_flag:0                  
                    })
    }
    sample(){
        this.setState({button_flag:1});
    }
    
    onchangeevent(name,event)
    {
        this.setState({button_flag:0});
        var change = {};
        change[name] = event.target.value;
        this.setState(change);
    }
    
    
    render() {
    return (
        <div className="">
        <div className="">
            <input type="text" value={this.state.name} name="name" onChange={this.onchangeevent.bind(this,"name")}/>
            <input type="text" value={this.state.age} name="age" onChange={this.onchangeevent.bind(this,"age")}/>
            {this.state.button_flag === 1 && 
            <div>
            <h3>{this.state.name} : {this.state.age}</h3>             
            </div>
            }
        </div>
        <p className="">
            <button onClick={this.sample.bind(this)}>test</button>
            
            
            <Link to="About">About</Link>
        </p>
        
                    <Route path="About" component={About}/>

        </div>
    );
    }
}

export default App;
```

About

```js
import React,{Component} from 'react';      
class About extends Component{              
    render(){
        return(
            <div>   <p> hi  </p>     </div>
        );
        }                               
    }
export default About;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your routes configuration should be like this.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import promise from 'redux-promise';

import reducers from './reducers';
import App from './App';
import AboutComponent from './components/AboutComponent';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(promise)(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/about" component={AboutComponent} />
            <Route path="/" component={App} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('.container'));
```

Then shange your `Link` where route is getting activated to,

```
<Link to={`about`}>
  About
</Link>
```

Hope this helps. Happy coding !

Comment: Actually im new to react redux can u explain  Provider,applyMiddleware, createstore, reducer, promise  in your answer y ,when n how do v use

Comment: That's how you create your store using the redux-promise middleware. It merely returns a function, which can be called with your reducers to create the store. Finally you pass the store to the provider.